# How to implement Nuance Speechkit when using CocoaPods in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, speech-to-text, speechkit

Between the pod spec and what is currently on S.O. I had a tough time figuring out how to get speech-to-text working using SpeechKit + CocoaPod + Swift. Finally got it working so figured I'd help the next poor soul that comes looking for help! :)

Answer (score 2):

1. First install the CocoaPod: https://cocoapods.org/pods/SpeechKit
2. Add `#import <SpeechKit/SpeechKit.h>` to your bridging header
3. Login to Nuance's dev portal and create an app: https://developer.nuance.com/
4. Clean up the demo code so that is is more organized. I just wanted as much of the code to be in one place as possible so you can see a fully working implementation.

**Then create a UIViewController and add the following code with the correct credentials:**

```
import UIKit
import SpeechKit

class SpeechKitDemo: UIViewController, SKTransactionDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//!!link this to a corresponding button on the UIViewController in I.B.
@IBAction func tappedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    // All fields are required.
    // Your credentials can be found in your Nuance Developers portal, under "Manage My Apps".
    let SKSAppKey = "[Get this from the nuance app info page]";
    let SKSAppId = "[Get this from the nuance app info page]";
    let SKSServerHost = "[Get this from the nuance app info page]";
    let SKSServerPort = "[Get this from the nuance app info page]";

    let SKSLanguage = "eng-USA";

    let SKSServerUrl = "nmsps://\(SKSAppId)@\(SKSServerHost):\(SKSServerPort)"

    let session = SKSession(URL: NSURL(string: SKSServerUrl), appToken: SKSAppKey)


    //this starts a transaction that listens for voice input
    let transaction = session.recognizeWithType(SKTransactionSpeechTypeDictation,
        detection: .Short,
        language: SKSLanguage,
        delegate: self)
    print(transaction)
}

//required delegate methods
func transactionDidBeginRecording(transaction: SKTransaction!) {  }
func transactionDidFinishRecording(transaction: SKTransaction!) {  }
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didReceiveRecognition recognition: SKRecognition!) {

    //Take the best result
    let topRecognitionText = recognition.text;

    print("Best rec test: \(topRecognitionText)")
    //Or iterate through the NBest list
    let nBest = recognition.details;
    for phrase in (nBest as! [SKRecognizedPhrase]!) {
        let text = phrase.text;
        let confidence = phrase.confidence;
        print("\(confidence): \(text)")
    }



}
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didReceiveServiceResponse response: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {  }
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didFinishWithSuggestion suggestion: String!) {  }
func transaction(transaction: SKTransaction!, didFailWithError error: NSError!, suggestion: String!) {  }



}
```

Comment: I know get a issue in debugger that prevents me from doing inspection: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'SpeechKit'

Comment: When I implement this with my sandbox credentials (app key, app id, host, port) I keep getting the following error when I execute the code: "Recorder Error Code:1 Message:Failed to open stream. Internal Error -50."  Do you know what could be causing this?